# DGHV Bootstrap - How can I recrypt my cipherbit

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm implementing this homomorphic crypto-system : http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/440
I'm using SAGE math.

I don't get how the bootstrap is done in this scheme, in the appendix A, they say `Apply the decryption circuit to the expanded ciphertext z and the encrypted secret key bits σi`, thing that I don't understand since the decryption circuit requires a modulo 2.

How then I should apply the modulo on a cipherbit (and by staying in the cipherworld, using the public key and never decrypt)? (in their implementation, they are using the `recrypt` function, which I don't understand at all)

Comment: Usually, the bootstrap is done by simplifying the decryption algorithm (to lower its multiplicative depth) and putting more information in the public key (to compensate this simplification). What did you not understand? Is it an issue regarding this paper or the general concept of bootstrapping?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because this is more about using some specific software (and implementation for this software), than it is about cryptography as defined in our help center. If you can/want to reword it with an edit, please do so... thanks.